# PHP Classes and Code Organization

Tags: php, performance, class, oop, code-organization

Well I'm currently working on reworking the PHP backend (sorta making my own CMS) on a a personal website for fun as well as using it as a learning opportunity.

I've been attempting to learn OOP methods in PHP, as classes seem like a great way to keep code more organized and minimize code reuse. (Though code-reuse isn't necessarily more prevalent in non-oop systems if designed correctly)

My question regards how I should handle organizing different classes:

I organized my project on a piece of paper in a form similar to this:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<?php
    class main_website{
        #Has a bunch of universal configuration such as a connection to the database
        function __construct($includes='webpage1.class.php'){
            #will include anything listed above
        }
    }
    class users extends main_website{
        #functions relating to users
    }
    class webpages extends main_website{
        #functions relating to all web-pages
    }
    class webpage1 extends webpages{
        #has a set of functions that relate specifically to webpage 1 and won't be used elsewhere
    }
    class webpage2 extends webpages{
        #has a set of functions that relate specifically to webpage 2 and won't be used elsewhere
    }
?>
```

Now, this has been working well...ish. But I'm getting to a point where I'm creating several classes that at some point will need to communicate through each other; currently my solution is to have them communicate through their parent class, however having "sibling" classes talking to each other seems hacky so I'd like to ask **if I'm understanding OOP correctly or not**.

A lot of the posts on OOP are so varied and so many people have such wide views on code design and I'm not sure which ways are "right". (at least...right in terms getting my project to be somewhat "standard")

Comment: Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKD2-MAkXyQ

Comment: @Axalix That video actually did give me a completely new method to be looking at; luckily my code is still enough in it's infancy to where this shouldn't be too difficult and I will look further into this.

Comment: You are welcome. I remember long time ago this link was also useful for me: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look to use a dependency injection container, for example Symfony's [Dependency Injection component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) (which can be used stand-alone as explained in the article) to handle this communication.

This will make the loading of classes more efficient (utilising [lazy instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)) and also make your classes easier to unit test in isolation.

Comment: Thank you for this answer; you're the second person to point me to a dependency injection component within about 2 minutes so I'll assume it's definitely something I should look into and will be doing over these next few days.